# Using a chef cookbook in my own cookbook error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf

So I am new to chef and want to use chef-patch in my own recipes. I added `cookbook 'patch', '~> 2.2.1'` to my Berksfile and did `sudo berks install`
 and it installs it. But when I run my recipe it says `ERROR: undefined method 'replace' for #<Chef::Recipe:0x00000003cab450>`

Is there something I need to add to my fix.rb code.

```
replace "/etc/login.defs" do
       replace "PASS_MAX_DAYS 60"
       with "PASS_MAX_DAYS 59"
end
```

Comment: How are you using Chef? Is this inside Test Kitchen?

Comment: Chef-client/chef-solo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct link between Berkshelf and either of those. You need to use `berks upload` to send things to the Chef server for use with `chef-client`, and for `chef-solo` the workflow is up to you (though will probably involve `berks vendor` to write the cookbooks out at some point). You also need `depends 'patch'` in your `metadata.rb`.

Comment: so i ran `sudo berks vendor` added depends 'patch' to the metadata.rb and ran chef-client --local and same error

Comment: With local mode you would need to make sure the cookbooks are located in `./cookbooks/` specifically, not `.`. As I said though, non-Server workflows are much less documented as they are advanced-level stuff and so we assume you are taking responsibility for making it work.